# What does "Missing Recommends" in Synaptic package manager mean?

Tags: synaptic

In the Synaptic Package Manager, under 'Custom Filters,' what is the "Missing Recommends' entry?

Comment: see also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/135909/which-packages-recommended-missing-recommends/156202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That filter lists packages that should (but aren't required to) be installed. Those packages are packages recommended by others. For example, OpenOffice.org would appear in that filter if you uninstall OO.org. Your system should work correctly if have packages in that list.